# How to Handle Failed database Restoration and set it to multiuser mode everytime after database restoration fails abnormally?

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-express

This is the code i am using to restore database

```
SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("server=.\\SQLExpress;Persist Security Info= True;integrated security=True;Trusted_Connection=Yes");
                c.Open();
//Setting database into single user mode first
                SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE Society_security_database SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", c);
                cd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//Restoring database from a location
                cd = new SqlCommand("RESTORE DATABASE Society_security_database FROM DISK = '" + path + "' WITH REPLACE", c);
                cd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//Finally setting it to MultiUSermode again
                cd = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE Society_security_database SET MULTI_USER", c);
                cd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
                c.Close();
```

But when restoration fails the 3rd query not executing and program aborts abnormally, How to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the exact exception and error details? You may need to close and reopen the connection.

Comment: using a try, catch, finally block.

Comment: @tschmit007 I did this too but Finally Block not executing too i dunno why  . 
I have added this code in finally block 

`finally
{
SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("server=.\\SQLExpress;Persist Security Info= True;integrated security=True;Trusted_Connection=Yes");
                    c.Open();
                    string quer = "exec sp_dboption 'Society_security_database', 'single user', 'FALSE'";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(quer,c);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    c.Close();
}`

Comment: @akton 
How a user will open and close connection , actually application fails to fetch data from database after thn , can say connection lose!